# Group/Aggragate rows by Geography Points distance in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, gis

I have a table with millions of rows, each containing a Geography Point (lat long) and a price per square meter (real estate prices).

I am displaying the prices on a map. Given a viewport, I would like to select all rows in the DB that fall within that viewport and group them so that I always return a maximum of 1,000 results and the average price per square meter for every of these 1,000 rows.

Comment: "Group them". By what criteria? It sounds like what you want is `select top(1000) from dbo.yourTable where <point is in view port>`. What am I missing? Also, are you using geospatial data types?

Comment: Yes I am using geospatial data types. I want to group them by their it distance from one another. Several points would become one. Their would aggregate / merge. And the price per square meter of the aggregated point would become the average of its constituents.

Comment: Alright. Let's walk this through. So you want to collapse multiple points into one. Let's assume for simplicity that you want to do it based on bands of distance from the center of the viewport (e.g. 0-1000m, 1001-2000m, etc). As with any aggregate, you need to have a representative of the group. You state "Several points would become one.". Would you pick one from the group arbitrarily? Try to find some centroid of the group and display that? Some other option? Once you define the grouping, calculating the average price/square meter should be easy (if you have the area and price per member).